# Is there any SDK for the new Nokia 3310?

Tags: sdk, nokia

As [confirmed by Nokia](https://www.nokia.com/en_int/phones/nokia-3310), the old phone is returning with new hardware.

Will we be able to easily develop anything for the beloved phone?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

I can’t speak for the 2G version, but the new Nokia 3310 3G does appear to support some J2ME apps. I was able to install the last release of the Google Maps app, a weather app, and an email app that actually appears on the Opera Mini store. Some jads do say they’re not supported (Note Plus 4) and one had the character sets all messed up (Anyview EBook reader).

EDIT: I confirmed that I was able to side load an (untrusted) app I developed (a very long time ago) using Java 2 Micro Edition SDK.

Comment: What exactly does this mean? a) you can have some apps of their "walled garden type" appstore, or b) you could develop an app yourself and load/add it to the phone?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace I'm sideloading jar/ jad files that are downloaded/ over USB. Their store isn't much of a walled garden, really - it's just a place where you download jar/ jad files. So it seems like you could develop a J2ME app and sideload it on the phone (which would be just another jar/ jad file). Two things that aren't clear: a) some apps I tried sideloading said they weren't compatible with the device. I don't know what was incompatible, and b) I'm not sure if the app has to be signed in some manner. I'm happy to try an unsigned jar that isn't malicious if someone points me to one.

Comment: So I just dug up my old J2ME final project for the Fall 2004 semester of EECS 382. It was originally supposed to target the Nokia NGage, though the test hardware mysteriously never showed up in time for our presentation. Anyway, it totally worked on the 3310. It's not signed- it just throws up an "untrusted app" warning and lets you proceed. So, seems like you could build something in the Java ME SDK and sideload it.

Comment: @KeithKurak when you say you side loaded some apps, is it as simple as dropping a jar / jad file into a directory when the phone is connected as a mass storage device?

Comment: @JayKyburz yes. Drop the JAR on, disconnect, go to the file manager on the phone and run it.

Answer (score 5):

It was also my first question that came to mind after the unveiling of the new 3310. I was hoping for a nostalgic throwback to mobile java apps.

However, it seems like the OS (s30+) doesn't support J2ME, so definitely no third-party java apps. I guess there might be a slim chance they'd add some kind of app store by the time they release the new 3310, in which case you could develop apps in MRE SDK (maui runtime environment). If I'm not mistaken MRE is in C.

Comment: It's so disappointing the new 3310 doesn't run Java. I would definitely have bought one if it did. :-(

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_30%2B Wiki confirms: OS: s30+ and possibly MRE.

Comment: from here https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8843617 : "The Nokia 220 is — after the Nokia 108 — the second phone from Nokia which uses MediaTek Feature Phone MAUI as operating system, called Nokia Series 30+."
"The new Nokia Series 30+ platform (MediaTek) does not allow to add apps."

Hard to believe... 21st century...

Comment: @mr_lou New Nokia 3310 3G supports java. If you're looking for one. Otherwise I agree with Shurik.

Comment: @PulathisiBandara Source? I can't find anything to confirm that. Example: https://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_3310_3g-8876.php
"Java: No"

Comment: @mr_lou I believe the gsmarena website is not updated by the product developers. If you're looking for clues here it is, https://www.nokia.com/en_int/phones/nokia-3310-3g see full specs. 
Also if you're aware of the second answer to the question, someone has already developed an application(unsigned).

Comment: Alright. It would have helped if they'd included the word "Java" on the page. Then it would have been searchable. ;-) But instead they've just put the Java logo. But ok, I'm convinced. :-)