# Nokia 3310: MIDlet always gives "Can't compile the file"

Tags: java-me, nokia, midlet, midp-2.0

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42489241/is-there-any-sdk-for-the-new-nokia-3310#comment81990636_47106846) comment proving that it's possible to write custom apps for the new [Nokia 3310 3G (TA-1006)](https://www.nokia.com/phones/en_int/nokia-3310-3g), I'm trying to get my own app running.

After doing a lot of reading about what MIDP, CLDC etc. are, I installed the [Java ME SDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/javame-sdk/downloads/javamesdkdownloads-2166598.html) (on a fresh Ubuntu installation since Oracle only supports that or Windows), [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/photon/) and the [Sun Wireless toolkit](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html).

First of, I couldn't find any information on which version of MIDP and CLDC are supported by the device, so I went ahead and tried a few possible permutations, these are my results:

```
CLDC \ MIDP | 1.0 | 2.0 | 2.1 |
1.0         |  *  |  *  |  X  |
1.1         |  *  |  *  |  ?  |
1.8         |  X  |  X  |  ?  |
```

The `?` ones I have not tried since MIDP 2.1 does not work and there is nothing to be gained and the `X` ones give an error "*Can't install [MIDlet name] because it doesn't work with this phone*".

So it seems like the phone supports the MIDP 2.0 profile and CLDC 1.1 configurations, however when I try to install my app (with any of the configurations of `*`) it always goes like this:

1. "*[MIDlet name] is untrusted. Continue anyway?*" > Ok (this was expected)
2. "*Can't compile the file*" (here is where I'm stuck)

#### What I tried so far (besides the various version permutations)

- Initially I tried with a very basic MIDlet subtype:

```java
public void startApp()
{
    Form form = new Form("Hello");
    form.append(new StringItem("Hello", "World!");
    Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(form);
}
```

- Next, I tried using these templates provided by the Eclipse plugin:

  - Splash MIDlet Template
  - Hello World Midlet Template
- When selecting the runtime configuration (always picked `DefaultColorPhone`) I adjusted the version profile from `MIDP-2.1` to `MIDP-2.0`
- Tried the other configs `MediaControlSkin` and `QwertyDevice`

I always produced the `*.jar` and `.jad` files by clicking the "*Packaging > Create Package*" button in the "*Application Descriptor*" view.

At some point it became experimenting with various settings which I didn't have much confidence that it'll work, reading up and rinse-repeat. When looking for alternatives, the whole journey became quite frustrating since a lot of links are either on dodgy websites, 404s or for the old 3310 phone.

#### TL;DR

What configuration and build steps are necessary to get a simple (unsigned) application compiled for the new Nokia 3310?

---

Here are the full contents of the simplest failing example which imo should work:

```
$ tree
.
├── Application Descriptor
├── bin
│   └── com
│       └── stackoverflow
│           └── kvn
│               └── test
│                   └── SOExample.class
├── build.properties
├── deployed
│   └── DefaultColorPhoneM2.0
│       ├── SOTest.jad
│       └── SOTest.jar
├── res
└── src
    └── com
        └── stackoverflow
            └── kvn
                └── test
                    └── SOExample.java

13 directories, 6 files
$ cat Application\ Descriptor 
MIDlet-1: SOExample,,com.stackoverflow.kvn.test.SOExample
MIDlet-Jar-URL: SOTest.jar
MIDlet-Name: SOTest MIDlet Suite
MIDlet-Vendor: MIDlet Suite Vendor
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.0
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
$ cat build.properties 
# MTJ Build Properties
DefaultColorPhoneM2.0.includes=src/com/stackoverflow/kvn/test/SOExample.java\

DefaultColorPhoneM2.0.excludes=\

$ cat src/com/stackoverflow/kvn/test/SOExample.java 
package com.stackoverflow.kvn.test;

import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

public class SOExample extends MIDlet {

    private Form form;

    protected void destroyApp(boolean unconditional)
        throws MIDletStateChangeException { /* nop */ }

    protected void pauseApp() { /* nop */ }

    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        form = new Form("Hello");
        form.append(new StringItem("Hello", "World!"));
        Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(form);
    }
}
```

<sub>Software info of the device: Model: TA-1006; Software: 15.0.0.17.00; OS version: MOCOR_W17.44.3_Release; Firmware number: sc7701_barphone</sub>

Comment: NB: The apps worked with the emulator, so it's not the source code that is faulty.

Comment: Can you post the full source?

Comment: @mr_lou: I included the whole project structure and relevant (omitting contents of bytecodes) code.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing that stands out to me, is that the methods are `protected`. Never seen this before. Does anything change if you make them `public` instead?

Comment: Oh, and also try removing the `throws MIDletStateChangeException` from `destroyApp` and `startApp`

Comment: @mr_lou: I haven't thought about that yet, but unfortunately it didn't help: Just tried with the same code changing `protected` to `public` and removing the `throws ...` but it gave the same error "*Can't compile the file*" :( Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Just tried the other possibilities, `protected` with `throws` and `public` without `throws`, but still the same.

Comment: Alright. Well nothing is wrong with the source. Which version of the SDK did you get? You should try v3.4 instead of v8.

Comment: Does your Nokia 3310 run this?
http://www.ukkosjourney.com/NokiaTester.jar

Comment: @mr_lou: Yes, got the 8.3 one. Will try that later, need to go just now. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, is that url safe? I'm a bit hesitant (read paranoid) to download a .jar from the internet without knowing the source well.

Comment: Oracle messed up. SDK 3.4 is the last one that handles MIDlets, while v8.x handles Xlets. You shouldn't even be able to compile a MIDlet using v8.x though...
But it's a mess. You're far from the first one to fall into that.

Comment: Sounds promising, I'm looking forward to try that out! Got my hopes up again :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189215/discussion-between-kvn-and-mr-lou).